# Libstpotify API - How can I login with my Facebook credentials?

Tags: spotify

Old-school* Spotify pseudo/password credentials work with Libspotify-based apps while Facebook credentials don't.

So how do users login to a Libspotify-based app with their Facebook account ?

*Before Facebook accounts became mandatory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of libSpotify 11 Facebook login should work fine — just have the user login with their Facebook email address and password.

If you're on iOS, you must use the login flow supplied with the library (`SPLoginViewController` and friends) - see the sample applications for how to do this.